# Lambda event filtering for DynamoDB trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Here is a modified version of an `Event` type I am receiving in my handler for a lambda function with a DynamoDB `someTableName` table trigger that I logged using cargo lambda.

```
Event { 
    records: [
        EventRecord { 
            change: StreamRecord { 
                approximate_creation_date_time: ___ 
                keys: {"id": String("___")}, 
                new_image: {
                   ....
                    "valid": Boolean(true), 
                }, 
               ...
            }, 
            ...
            event_name: "INSERT", 
            event_source: Some("aws:dynamodb"), 
            table_name: None 
        }
    ] 
}
```

Goal: Correctly filter with `event_name=INSERT && valid=false`

I have tried a number of options, for example;
`{"eventName": ["INSERT"]}`
While the filter is added correctly, it does not trigger the lambda on item inserted.

Q1) What am I doing incorrectly here?

Q2) Why is table_name returning None? The lambda function is created with a specific table name as trigger. The returned fields are returning an option (Some(_)) so I'm asssuming it returns None if the table name is specified on lambda creation, but seems odd to me?

Q3) From AWS Management Console > Lambda > ... > Trigger Detail, I see the following (which is slightly different from my code mentioned above), where does "key" come from and what does it represent in the original `Event`?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Filters must follow the [documented syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-basics) for filtering in the Event Source Mapping between Lambda and DynamoDB Streams.

If you are entering the filter in the Lambda console:

```json
{ "eventName": ["INSERT"], "dynamodb": { "NewImage": {"valid": { "BOOL" : [false]}} } }
```

Comment: Thanks, to add, I referenced these docs and tried all the suggested context, but didn't see them working. It turns out I was just not being patient enough, as the lambdas were firing about 10min later. (Or that's when they showed on the logs) I don't have a decent explanation to explain the lags.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a filter example with boolean, I wasn't sure if the value should be "false" or false without double quotes, the documentation doesn't specify this. Now it's clearer

Answer (score 1):

The attribute name is actually eventName, so your filter should look like this:

```
{"eventName": ["INSERT"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complex filter criteria around the same theme could be entered via the AWS Console. `{"awsRegion": ["eu-west-1"], "dynamodb": {  "NewImage": {"stored_all_batched_content": { "BOOL" : [true]}},"StreamViewType": ["NEW_IMAGE"]  },"eventName": ["MODIFY"],  "eventSource": ["aws:dynamodb"]}`